# tf.Estimator - Route TensorBoard logs to different dir than model's dir

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

When using the TF Estimator API, the TensorBoard logs are automatically saved in what is defined as the `model_dir` upon creating the estimator.

Is it possible to separate those dirs? Save model checkpoints to one dir while logging TensorBoard's logs into another?

Answer (score -1):

Just copy the events file to the other directory

Comment: This doesn't answer OP question